# Writing test for form(including useState)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I want to write a test for my form that handles with react hook (use state) and also I'm using **reactstrap**.

Package.json

**"enzyme": "^3.11.0",**

**"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.5",**

Here's my code in **UserInput** componenet:

```
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;

    setEachEntry({ ...eachEntry, [event.target.name]: value });
};

  <FormGroup>
    <Label for="number">Number of simulations</Label>
        <Input
            name="number"
            type="number"
            placeholder="e.g. 10, 20"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            value={number}
            />
    </FormGroup>
                
    <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Simulate</Button>
```

and here's the code in **UserInput.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import UserInput from "./UserInput";

describe("check user input form", () => {

    let wrapper = mount(<UserInput/>);


    it('should set the password value on change event with trim', () => {
        wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: 1,
            },
        });
        expect(wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
    });
})
```

But I got an error when run the test :

```
  ● check user input form › should set the password value on change event with trim

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: ""

      31 |                      },
      32 |              });
    > 33 |              expect(wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
         |                                                                         ^
      34 |      });
      35 | })
      36 |
```

Any idea would be appreciate it ?

**
**Update/Solution**
**

Thanks to Johannes for the help, I needed to use `act` and also `update()` to updated the component.

```
it('should set the password value on change event with trim', async () => {
        await act(async () => {
             wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').simulate('change', {
                target: {
                    name:'number',
                    value: 1,
                },
            });
        });
        wrapper.update();
        expect(wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since state setting is a async operation you have to wrap you handler in `act()`, so that jest can wait for the result of the operation.

```js
describe("check user input form", () => {

    let wrapper = mount(<UserInput/>);


    it('should set the password value on change event with trim', () => {
        act(() => wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').simulate('change', {
            target: {
                value: 1,
            },
        }));
        expect(wrapper.find('input[type="number"]').prop('value')).toEqual(1);
    });
})
```

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-adapter-react-16#reacttestutilsact-wrap for more details.

Comment: Hi @Johannes, thanks for the answer but i got the     `ReferenceError: act is not defined`

Comment: You of course have to import it via `import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';` or via enzyme.

Comment: now I got the new error
`    console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:87
      Warning: The callback passed to act(...) function must return undefined, or a Promise. You returned [object Object]
`

Comment: @Sadeghbayan it just takes the callback passed to act to not return anything or to return a promise